# Rails validate model with attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to do a custom validation that checks if the attribute being updated is less than another attribute on that record. I tried doing this:

```
validates :team_size, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => self.users.count }
```

But it comes back with the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `users' for #<Class:0x007fcda9a548e8>):
```

I also tried doing a `before_save` hook with a method like this:

```
  def validate_team_size
    if self.team_size < self.users.count
      errors[:base] << "Custom message."
    end
  end
```

But it just ignores it - I'm assuming because the `team_size` attribute hasn't been updated yet so I'm checking the old value. Also tried using `after_save` which is just before it commits but no luck either.

Comment: after_save is definitely not what you want to use in this case.
(More, all the self you wrote can be omitted.) Can you post your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you had was close.  Try something like this..

```
validate :team_size_less_than_users_count

def team_size_less_than_users_count
  if team_size < users.count
    errors[:base] << "Custom message."
  end
end
```

To access instance variables, you do it like this...

```
validates_numericality_of :team_size, :greater_than_or_equal_to => Proc.new {|c| c.users.count }, :message => 'Custom message'
```

This syntax works as well

```
validates :team_size, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => Proc.new {|c| c.users.count }, :message => 'Custom message'}
```

Comment: So close! That works, thank you. Would you know why the validates numericality didn't have access to the attributes on itself?